# Ionic5 App connection to SupaBase gives "process is not defined"

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic5, supabase

Hello I have the following problem:

I wanted to test a few small things with the "new" SupaBase service.

I have also implemented everything using an example angularapp.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/supabase-angular-example

Now I get the following error when starting:
[image: Text]

the error occurs if the service is defined in the constructor.

Does anyone have any experience with the exact cause of the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>This is a bug. We're working on it now:</s>

This is now fixed:

https://github.com/supabase/supabase-js/issues/113

Make sure you are on the latest version of supabase-js:

```
npm install @supabase/supabase-js@latest
```

(I'm a maintainer)